# Using CollectionExpression in QueryDSL

Tags: java, querydsl

In the QueryDSL library, the `com.mysema.query.types.expr.SimpleExpression<T>` class has a `SimpleExpression.in(CollectionExpression<?, ? extends T>)` method which is supposed to take an expression which is supposed to return a collection. But I cannot find a way to create an object of type `com.mysema.query.types.CollectionExpression<?, ? extends T>`.

My query expression looks like this:

```
QEvent.event.organization.in(expression)
```

where i want the `expression` to be something like:

```
QOrganization.organization.country.in("India", "USA")
```

But the second expression is of type `com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanExpression` and I am unable to find a way to convert it to `com.mysema.query.types.CollectionExpression<?, ? extends T>`.

I looked in the [QueryDSL API docs](http://source.mysema.com/static/querydsl/2.1.2/apidocs/) but could not find anything relevant.

Comment: What is the type of `organization` in `QEvent`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't convert a BooleanExpression into CollectionExpression, for the same reasons why you can't convert a java.lang.Boolean into a java.util.Collection. They aren't compatible.

What would the following expression mean to you

```
QEvent.event.organization.in( 
    QOrganization.organization.country.in("India", "USA"))
```

Do you maybe try to express something like this?

```
QEvent event = QEvent.event;
QOrganization organization = QOrganization.organization;
query.from(event)
    .innerJoin(event.organization, organization)
    .where(organization.country.in("India", "USA"))
    .list(event);
```

Or simpler

```
QEvent event = QEvent.event;
query.from(event)
    .where(event.organization.country.in("India", "USA"))
    .list(event);
```

I guess what you tried to describe was an Expression using subqueries. Something like this

```
query.from(event)
    .where(event.organization.in( subQuery().from(organization)
        .where(organization.country.in("India", "USA")))
    .list(event);
```

The implementation of subQuery() is Querydsl backend specific. If you use a join then you get a row for each matching event - organization combination and with subqueries you get unique events which have organizations meeting the given constraints.

Performance differences of join vs subquery are implementation specific.

Which Querydsl backend do you use? JPA, SQL or something else?

Comment: I am using JPA as QueryDSL backend. And you are right, I was trying to go the subquery way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it like that, it wouldn't make sense on the DB side, anyway.

You have to [use a SubQuery](http://source.mysema.com/static/querydsl/2.1.2/reference/html/ch02s02.html#d0e522)